# Emit Event from within Evaluate CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I'm having a problem downloading files from urls I am creating when scrapping a website. Currently I discovering the month and year of a file then replacing the values in a url and downloading trying to download from that location. I understand that you can't use the download function from inside the evaluation scope.

```
this.evaluate(function collectAllData (MONTHS) {
    for (...) {
        // Create url from page information ...
        casper.emit('test.download', url, fileName); 
    }
}, MONTHS);

casper.on('remote.download', function processRemoteDownload(url, fileName) {
    this.download(url, fileName);
});
```

Is there anyway to emit a custom event from within evaluate? I don't want to navigate away from the current page I am on or have to go back and forth from the evaluate scope. I know I could return a list of urls and process them after the fact but was curious if this was possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use inside the `evaluate` callback:

```js
console.log("casper-event:add:[1234]");
```

then can do it like this (not tested):

```js
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
   if(msg.indexOf("casper-event:" == 0))
   {
       var event = msg.replace(/^casper-event:/, '').replace(/:.*$/, '');
       var result = JSON.parse(msg.replace(/^casper-event:.*?:/, ''));
       this.emit(event, result);
   }
})

casper.on('add'........
```

Comment: This looks clear and probably works. Instead of `console.log`, there is also the native `callPhantom` from [phantomjs docs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#oncallback) to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
casper.then(function getDOMLoaded(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        window.__DOMLoaded = false;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            window.__DOMLoaded = true;
        })
    })
});
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.getGlobal('__DOMLoaded');
}, function then() {    // step to execute when check() is ok
    casper.echo("DOMContentReady in " + (Date.now()-start) + " ms", "INFO_BAR");
}, function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
    casper.echo("DOMContentReady took longer than 10 seconds!")
}, 10000);
```

It sets a global variable, which is updated in the WebPage via `evaluate`. I then run a `waitFor` which attempts (for 10s) to check whether `window.__DOMLoaded` is true (however, within casper but not evaluate, this is accessed via `this.getGlobal()`